# Retriving xyz coordinates and plotting in a 3d graph in python

Tags: python, 3d

I have a set of x y z coordinates and im attempting to plot a 3-d graph with it. My text files will have 3 values for each row, each separated by a "tab" spacing.

My codes are below:

```
xv = []
yv = []
zv = []
fig6 = plt.figure()
ax6 = fig6.gca(projection='3d')
with open('C:\Python27\Generate_Data\Posi_ture1803.txt') as f:
for line in f:
    a, b, c = line.split('\t')
    xv.append(a)
    yv.append(b)
    zv.append(c)
ax6.plot(xv, yv, zs=zv, label='True Position')
ax6.legend()
```

And the following is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Generate_Data\gen_vehicle_location.py", line 155, in <module>
fig6.savefig('True Position.png')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1363, in savefig
self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 2093, in      print_figure
**kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 491, in print_png
FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 439, in draw
self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 999, in draw
func(*args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\axes3d.py", line 214, in draw
Axes.draw(self, renderer)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 54, in draw_wrapper
draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 2086, in draw
a.draw(renderer)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\art3d.py", line 117, in draw
xs, ys, zs = proj3d.proj_transform(xs3d, ys3d, zs3d, renderer.M)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\proj3d.py", line 194, in proj_transform
return proj_transform_vec(vec, M)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\proj3d.py", line 153, in proj_transform_vec
vecw = np.dot(M, vec)
ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize
```

my set of values are like as follow

```
0   0   0
4.755282581 1.545084972 1
9.510565163 3.090169944 2
14.26584774 4.635254916 3
19.02113033 6.180339887 4
```

Comment: I guess it expects values instead of strings, but please post the file (or an excerpt) as well

Comment: I have added the sample of the text file. This are the first 5 values.

Comment: Use `a, b, c = map(float, line.split('\t'))` to convert the values read from strings to real numbers.

Comment: OMG! Got it working. But I keep getting BSOD after a few tries! Is it because of the for loop to read the file?